# infinite direct sum of isometries

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $H, K$ are two Hilbert spaces, let $\oplus K$ be the inifinite direct sum of $K$, if there exists an isometry $V$ from $\oplus K$ to $H$. In Davidson's book, the author mentions that  we  can write $V$ as the form of $(V_1,\cdots,V_n,\cdots).$, where each $V_i$ is an isomery. How to define each $V_i$? [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your direct sum is a countably infinite direct sum $\oplus K_i$,  $V_n$ is simply the restriction of $V$ to $K_n$.

Comment: You mean that $V_i(h)=V(0,\cdots, 0,  h, 0,\cdots)$ where $h$ is the i-th place?         
 If we define as the above? How to show that $V(h_1,\cdots,h_n,\cdots)=(V_1,V_2, \cdots, )(h_1,\cdots,h_n,\cdots)$? The latter is $(V_1h_1,V_2h_2,\cdots)$, but we don't know the value of $V(h_1,\cdots,h_n,\cdots)$